# Price elasticity of demand/supply following tech change

Tags: microeconomics, elasticity, price

[image]
Is the answer (b) ?
I found the two equilibrium prices before and after the change by doing Q^D = Qs1, Q^D = Qs2.
Before the change, I get for the supply side : P = 15 and Q = 5, giving me a price elasticity of supply -> (Qs'(P))*P/Q = (3x5)/15 = 1
.After the change, I get for the supply side: P= 16 and Q = 4, giving me a price elasticity of supply -> (Qs'(P))*P/Q = (4x4)/16 = 1

Comment: You are correct. (Though note when you stated the equilibrium prices and quantities you reversed the price and quantity. You used the correct values in the calculations though.)